# Zeta function convergence, confusing passage in book

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book Complex Analysis by Theodore Gamelin, on page 371, the Zeta function is defined:
$\zeta(s) = \sum \frac{1}{n^s}$
,
$\sigma = Re s > 1$

Continuing: "The series converges absolutely for $\sigma > 1$, and it converges uniformly for $\sigma \geq 1+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$."

Forgive my ignorance, but are not the sets $\{\sigma > 1\}$ and $\{\sigma : \sigma \geq 1+\epsilon, \forall \epsilon > 0\}$ identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not.  $\{\sigma: \sigma \ge 1 + \epsilon,\; \forall \epsilon > 0\} = \emptyset$.   Maybe you mean $\{\sigma: \exists \epsilon > 0, \sigma \ge 1 + \epsilon\}$.   However, that's not what the author is talking about.  For any given $\epsilon > 0$, the convergence is uniform on $\{\sigma \ge 1 + \epsilon\}$.  However, it is not uniform on $\{\sigma > 1\}$.

For a simpler example: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ converges to $1/(1-x)$ on $[0,1)$.
The convergence is uniform on $[0,1-\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.  However,
it is not uniform on $[0,1)$.